# Change text alignment based on content

Tags: html, css

I got "Title", "Description " and Buttons. Based on the below scenarios i wanted to display the content(Given a reference link for each scenarios)

Scenario 1: Title with Description & two buttons
‘Title’ is positioned at the top with the ‘description’ left aligned below the title. Two normal CTA buttons are in-line with the ‘description’.

[image: Scenario 1]

Scenario 2: Tile with Description & one button
‘Title’ is positioned at the top with the ‘description’ left aligned below the title. One normal CTA button is in-line with the ‘description’.

[image: Scenario 2]

Scenario 3:Title with Description & No buttons
‘Title’ is positioned at the top with the centre aligned description below without CTA buttons.

Scenario 4: Title with one or two buttons/ No Description
`Title` and buttons should be in the same line

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.cta {
  display: table;
}

.cta-content,
.cta-title,
.cta-button {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!-- Scenario 1-->
<div class="cta-module row bottom-divider text-center">
  <div class="cta content-wrapper col-12">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Achieve your goal</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-content">
      <p>Whether it's a new or second-hand car, a personal loan can help you pay for your car if you don't have the funds up front.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-button">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Find out more</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Find out more</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Scenario 2-->
<div class="cta-module row bottom-divider text-center">
  <div class="cta content-wrapper col-12">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Achieve your goal</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-content">
      <p>Whether it's a new or second-hand car, a personal loan can help you pay for your car if you don't have the funds up front.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-button">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Find out more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Scenario 3-->
<div class="cta-module row bottom-divider text-center">
  <div class="cta content-wrapper col-12">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Achieve your goal</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-content">
      <p>Whether it's a new or second-hand car, a personal loan can help you pay for your car if you don't have the funds up front.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Scenario 4-->
<div class="cta-module row bottom-divider text-center">
  <div class="cta content-wrapper col-12">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Achieve your goal</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-button">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Find out more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Above css doesn't work for all scenarios. I don't want to use javascript or Jquery unless their are no options in CSS. Please help

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you would like it to look like please

Comment: it should look like this url https://i.stack.imgur.com/btO9j.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy287.png

Comment: Are you able to change the structure of the html?

Comment: HTML structure can be changed.. But it should be common i.e no different html for each scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution similar to that of Pete ([Test it on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4j906ma/)) but for scenario 4 there is no way to achieve it only in HTML / CSS 
(as you would like). A few lines of JavaScript should not hurt the page.

(@Lokesh's solution does not work because its "alignLine" div is not placed in the same place in scenario 4)

```css
     .text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.cta-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.cta-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.cta-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Scenario 1-->
<div class="cta-module row bottom-divider text-center">
  <div class="cta content-wrapper col-12">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Achieve your goal</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <div class="cta-content">
        <p>Whether it's a new or second-hand car, a personal loan can help you pay for your car if you don't have the funds up front.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Find out more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Find out more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Scenario 2-->
<div class="cta-module row bottom-divider text-center">
  <div class="cta content-wrapper col-12">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Achieve your goal</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <div class="cta-content">
        <p>Whether it's a new or second-hand car, a personal loan can help you pay for your car if you don't have the funds up front.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Find out more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Scenario 3-->
<div class="cta-module row bottom-divider text-center">
  <div class="cta content-wrapper col-12">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Achieve your goal</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <div class="cta-content">
        <p>Whether it's a new or second-hand car, a personal loan can help you pay for your car if you don't have the funds up front.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Scenario 4-->
<div class="cta-module row bottom-divider text-center">
  <div class="cta content-wrapper col-12">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Achieve your goal</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Find out more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```